How to mount a CM4 in a virtualBox VM
I have a process to mount a raspberryPi Compute Module 4 (CM4) as a disk in order to flash it. I use rpiboot to do so and I can flash it without any complication on a Linux PC.
For testing purpose, I have to do the same thing but in a Linux VM on a Windows host.
My VM is installed and I have all the elements to proceed. I can see my CM4 when I plug the USB cable, doing "lsusb", but when I launch rpiboot from my VM the CM4 is mounted as a disk on Windows and not in my VM.
Despite the fact that rpiboot seems to proceed normally, I cannot see my CM4 in my Linux VM. Gparted only shows me my VM splitted on sda1, 2 and 3, nothing else.
Is there a particular setting that I could configure in my VM in order to be able to detect it and flash it from the VM ?
